# Using a CDN with expressJS

Tags: express, cdn, performance-testing

I start to play with ExpressJS for an app. I use the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` line to configure access to the public folder.

But as I use a CDN, I would like to point to the public folder who will contain JS, CSS & img files. This is an example :
`http://cdn.com/public/css/style.css`

Is anyone who can help me to fix the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Use a CDN" means "load files from the CDN's servers instead of your own app server". Thus when you use a CDN, your app server does not handle those files. You just need to change your URLs in your HTML to point to the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, CDN provider like MAXCdn are waiting for a readable folder. So, I'm looking for the express paramater that replace `__dirname`.

So I did a simple thing : add a repository nested. In this way, I get  `http://domain.tld/public/img/someImage.jpg` way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [express-simple-cdn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-simple-cdn) node module and then in Jade template use CDN() function:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href=CDN('/css/style.css'))
```

It would output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.com/public/css/style.css">
```